# Firefox add-on: HTTP Log that saves to text file with time, username, computername doesn't create text file

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I tried to modify a Firefox add-on to save HTTP request to the text file in location I mentioned, with system name and username with time (if the request contains "flag=unknown"). It is to monitor how my subordinates work on the site I gave. But it doesn't work. I don't know how to make it work. Below is my code

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm');
function HttpRequestLogger() {
  var httpRequestLogger = {
    observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
      if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
        var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
        var ref = httpChannel.referrer ? httpChannel.referrer.spec : "(none)";
        var buffer = ref + " " + httpChannel.requestMethod + " " 
                         + httpChannel.URI.spec + "\n";
        var n = buffer.search("flag=unknown");
        If (n > 0) {
          fos.write(buffer + "^" + ThisUserName + "^" + TimeStamp + "\r\n");
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var file = 'T:\test';
  file.append("log.txt");
  var fos = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
                      .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);

  fos.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x10, -1, 0);

  var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
  observerService.addObserver(httpRequestLogger, "http-on-modify-request", false);
}

HttpRequestLogger.prototype.classID = 
                                Components.ID('{c4a9bb50-b9b2-11e0-a4dd-0800200c9a66}');
HttpRequestLogger.prototype.classDescription = 'Http Request Logger XPCOM Component';
HttpRequestLogger.prototype.contractID = '@prekageo/HttpRequestLogger;1';
var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([HttpRequestLogger]);

var nsIEnvironment = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"]
                               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment);
var ThisUserName = nsIEnvironment.get("UserName");
var ThisUserName = nsIEnvironment.get("ComputerName");
var date = new Date();
var TimeStamp = date.toLocaleString();
```

FYKI:I don't know if it is wrong to leave the classID as it is.
credits for the original code goes to [@prekageo/HttpRequestLogger](https://github.com/prekageo/http-request-logger).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, **•a specific problem or error** *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In other words: How does it not work?  What error do you see (in the console)? What is it not doing that you expected it to do? etc.

Comment: Makyen, I've change the title. The above code doesnt create a text file in T:\test as log.txt even I click the button which makes the request that contains 'flag=unknown'.

Comment: What error(s) are you seeing in the console?

Comment: FYI: you redefine `ThisUserName`

Comment: I've changed it before my first reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first problem is that `file` is a string instead of the required [nsIFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFile) in the following statement:

```
fos.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x10, -1, 0);
```

See: [nsIFileOutputStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFileOutputStream) where it shows that `init()` has the following parameters:

```
void init(in nsIFile file, in long ioFlags, in long perm, in long behaviorFlags);
```

Note that it should also be an nsIFile for the statement: `file.append("log.txt");`

You should do something like the following:

```
...
var FileUtils = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm").FileUtils;

var file = new FileUtils.File( 'T:\\test' );
file.append("log.txt");
...
```

Problem two:
Note: the `\\` instead of `\` in `'T:\\test'`. A single `\` just quotes the next character in the string literal. You need the string to actually contain a `\`, thus it needs to be quoted with another `\`.

Problem three:
Your use of:

```
fos.write(buffer + "^" + ThisUserName + "^" + TimeStamp + "\r\n");
```

does not contain the required length count needed for [`write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIOutputStream#write%28%29).

Possible issue:
You are creating your `TimeStamp` once, outside of the observer.  This will result in a single time-stamp for all entries.

Solving those issues, cleaning up and optimizing a bit gives the following tested functional code:

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm');
function HttpRequestLogger() {
  var httpRequestLogger = {
    observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
      if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
        var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
        var ref = httpChannel.referrer ? httpChannel.referrer.spec : "(none)";
        var buffer = ref + " " + httpChannel.requestMethod + " " 
                         + httpChannel.URI.spec + "\n";
        searchRegExp.lastIndex = 0; //Make sure searching from begining.
        if(searchRegExp.test(buffer) ) {
          var date = new Date();
          var TimeStamp = date.toLocaleString();
          buffer += "^" + ThisUserName + "^" + TimeStamp + "\r\n";
          fos.write(buffer, buffer.length);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  //Explicitly define the RegExp here once so it is not implicitly done each time
  //  the observer is called. This saves time in the observer, which, if possible, we
  //  should code to be fast.
  var searchRegExp = /flag=unknown/;

  var FileUtils = Components.utils
                            .import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm").FileUtils;

  var file = new FileUtils.File( "T:\\test" );
  file.append("log.txt");

  var fos = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
                      .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
  // PR_WRONLY | PR_CREATE_FILE | PR_APPEND
  fos.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x10, -1, 0);


  var nsIEnvironment = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"]
                                 .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment);
  var ThisUserName = nsIEnvironment.get("UserName");
  var ThisComputerName = nsIEnvironment.get("ComputerName");

  var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
  observerService.addObserver(httpRequestLogger, "http-on-modify-request", false);
}

HttpRequestLogger.prototype.classID =
                                Components.ID('{c4a9bb50-b9b2-11e0-a4dd-0800200c9a66}');
HttpRequestLogger.prototype.classDescription = 'Http Request Logger XPCOM Component';
HttpRequestLogger.prototype.contractID = '@prekageo/HttpRequestLogger;1';
var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([HttpRequestLogger]);
```

The other files from the [prekageo/http-request-logger
repository on GitHub](https://github.com/prekageo/http-request-logger) did not require any changes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that makyen. Unfortunately I am not much familiar with javascript as still it doesn't create the text file even I removed the condition if (n>0) for "flag=unknown".

Comment: @Dhay: Ok, based on looking at this further I would suggest that you first verify that the code you are getting from: [http-request-logger](https://github.com/prekageo/http-request-logger/blob/master/components/httpRequestLogger.js) is functioning without any modifications. Then modify it to change the filename and limit the requests as you desire. The code you have started with is almost 4 years old, which is a very long time in Firefox add-ons. As it is, you appear to have multiple issues which you should limit both in development and in asking questions here.

Comment: Yes. It works just fine as it puts a http-request-log.txt in desktop and write the requests as I deleted my code and pasted the code from the link you gave. is "you should limit both in development and in asking questions here" mean I should ask this question somewhere else in this stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Dhay: Updated with full tested code, and mention of other problems. As to your question: No, I was not saying you should ask elsewhere. I was trying to impart that you made multiple changes to the code you started with. From a development point of view when you are having problems it is often a good idea to start from known working code and then make incremental changes testing after each one. That way you know precisely what was changed when it stopped working, or performing as expected. What you had was several changes which resulted in you not knowing where the problem was.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood. I just came here again to copy the code for get username and found you have updated with full code. (I was spending time to fix step by step as you say). For your code Just I had to change searchRegExp.test to buffer.search since it didnt work on my system dont know why. Anyhow thank you for your support for me.

Comment: @Dhay, I am glad to hear that it is working for you.  I'm surprised that you needed to change to `buffer.search` as the filtering was something I specifically tested.  If this answer solved your problem, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.  When you do so, we both gain reputation points and it indicates to anyone that reads the question that you obtained an answer which solved your problem.